# Jpa query and, or using

Tags: hibernate

I wrote a query but this query returns this error.Do you have any idea?I guess that I get this error because of parenthesis

```
 @Query("select u from Context u where u.user.id <> :userId and u.publicWatch = 1 and  u.isDeleted = 0 and (u.contextType.id  IN :contextTypeId  or u.status IN :status)")
Page<Context> findFilteredContexts(@Param("userId") Long userId,@Param("contextTypeId") List<Long> contextTypeId,@Param("status") List<String> status, Pageable pageable);
```

The error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: 
>   {vector} [select count(u) from com.huawei.ti.ei.web.domain.Context u where 
>   u.user.id <> :userId and u.publicWatch = 1 and  u.isDeleted = 0 and 
>   (u.contextType.id  IN (:contextTypeId_0_)  or u.status IN :status_0_, 
>   :status_1_)]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of hibernate you have to surround your IN parameters with parenthesis `(:status)` 
([HHH-5126](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5126))

Affected version 3.5.1 -3.6 but looking at the comment someone report newer version too...

Comment: No.It is a new version.^u.contextType.id  IN :contextTypeId^ is working.But the other IN is not working